# jQuery UI sortable - restore original position after ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When a user changes the order of a list element I update the database with the new order with ajax.

If however the database cannot save for some reason I through an error. How can I restore the original positions of the li elements?

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  opacity: '0.5',
  start: function(event,ui) { 
    var element = $(ui.item[0]);
    element.data('lastParent', element.parent());
  },
  update: function(e, ui) {
    var neworderSer = $(this).sortable("serialize");
    var neworderArray = $(this).sortable('toArray');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/btstadmin/pages/reorder.json",
        type: "post",
        dataType:"json",
        data: neworderSer,
        success: function(feedback) {
          notify('Reordered pages');
        },
        error: function(e) {
          $($(this).data('lastParent')).append(this);
          notify('Reordered pages failed', {
              status: 'error'
          });
        }
    });      
    for (var i=0; i < neworderArray.length; i++) {
      if (i==0) {
        $("#"+neworderArray[i]+" .pageNum").fadeOut().text( "Cover" ).fadeIn();
      }else {
        $("#"+neworderArray[i]+" .pageNum").fadeOut().text( "Page "+i ).fadeIn();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Really what I need is to store the entire Ul

```
<ul id="pageMenu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sortable ui-sortable">
    <li class="" id="item_4">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/4">keiths page1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="item_5">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/5">keiths page2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="item_6">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/6">keiths page3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:** When I use start: I get the extra code that sortable adds temporally. I need something like beforeStart or only capture the original item without the added inline style.

```
  start: function(event, ui) { 
    prevPositions = $(".sortable").html();
  },
```

This gives me:

```
<ul id="pageMenu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked sortable ui-sortable">
    <li class="" id="item_3">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/3">Cover</a>
    </li>
     <li class="" id="item_4" style="width: 261px; height: 54px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1000;">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/4">keiths page1</a>
    </li>
         <li class="ui-sortable-placeholder" style="visibility: hidden; height: 54px;"></li>
     <li class="" id="item_7">
        <a href="/btstadmin/pages/view/7">test page 2</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery UI` itself doesn't provide such functionality . So you can do this in either of the way :

- Sort element based on the id attribute and re-append to the sort-able
  container. HECTIC work.
- Create a replica of the sortable element and reset when required. EASIER one.

I prefer second option. Create replica

```
var unOrderedList = $("#sortable").html();
```

Use `refresh` or `refreshPositions`to then reset the list as. [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refreshPositions)

```
error: function(e) {
      $("#sortable").html(unOrderedList);
      $("#sortable").sortable("refreshPositions");
                 }
```

#### And Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/787/)

Comment: thanks. I am getting an error Uncaught ReferenceError: unOrderedList is not defined. I have start: function() { 
        var unOrderedList = $(".sortable").html();
      }, and I am getting the error from error: function(e) {
              $(".sortable").html(unOrderedList);

Comment: I put var unOrderedList = $("#sortable").html(); into the start function as I need to take the snapshot before the ajax call. $("#sortable").html(); records the elements as dragging is in progress with some extra html and css style added <li class="ui-sortable-placeholder" style="visibility: hidden; height: 54px;"></li>

Comment: you could make it global by just using unOrderedList = $(".sortable").html(); Tried it out and see if the error still persist

Comment: Yes I made it global and it work. The problem though is using the start: it captures the state as it is being dragged, where the Sortable plugin adds some temporary html. I need to capture each time before the start.